# mongodb aggregation returning different value compared to what was logged

Tags: mongodb, typescript

When I run the aggregatio the result and data are showing different values I don't understand why is this happening, how do I resolve this issue?

```
const data = await QuestionBank.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $and: [{
            question_sub_catagory: "Data Sufficiency"
        }, {
            difficulty_level: "Easy"
        }]
    }
},
    {
        $sample: {
            size: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                question_id: "$question_id",
                question_sub_catagory: "Data Sufficiency",
                difficulty_level: "Easy"
            }
        }
    }
], function(err: any, result: string) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
    console.log(result, "result");
    return result

})
console.log(data);
```

Output is:

```
[ { _id:
     { question_id: '3febc9ef-cb3e-42c7-bfb6-a18e780cab6c',
       question_sub_catagory: 'Data Sufficiency',
       difficulty_level: 'Easy' } } ]
```

Result is:

```
[ { _id:
     { question_id: '43abc9ef-cb3e-42c7-bfb6-a18e780cab6c',
       question_sub_catagory: 'Data Sufficiency',
       difficulty_level: 'Easy' } } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are mixing the syntax of callbacks and promises.

As a rule of thumb an async function signature will be ONE of the two. either return a promise which you can `await` or `.then()` on. OR call a callback function.

Mongo supports both types of calls. and by giving it a callback function your basically telling Mongo to not return a promise.

So either drop the callback:

```
const data = await QuestionBank.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {
                    question_sub_catagory: "Data Sufficiency"
                }, {
                    difficulty_level: "Easy"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $sample: {
            size: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                question_id: "$question_id",
                question_sub_catagory: "Data Sufficiency",
                difficulty_level: "Easy"
            }
        }
    }
]);
console.log(data);
```

Or wrap it in a promise to retain current structure (if for some reason it's needed):

```
const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    QuestionBank.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    {
                        question_sub_catagory: "Data Sufficiency"
                    }, {
                        difficulty_level: "Easy"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $sample: {
                size: 1
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    question_id: "$question_id",
                    question_sub_catagory: "Data Sufficiency",
                    difficulty_level: "Easy"
                }
            }
        }
    ], function (err: any, result: string) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err)
        };
        console.log(result, "result");
        resolve(result)
    })
})
console.log(data);
```